# PHP Extract data between specific tags from an html file

Tags: php, regex, domdocument

So I have a PHP script, which displays an html page. What I need to do, is to extract the innerHTML of a specific element, below I'll show the exact thing that I need to extract

So, what I need to extract is the `0.0225` sequence. Here is a fragment from an HTML file:

```
<tr>
    <td>Income</td>
    <td id="income">
        <font color="green">
            <span data-c="2250000">0.0225 RP</span>
        </font>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I tried parsing it with RegEx (I know that it is not recommended but I tried it) and I didn't got nothing. I've tried different DOM implementations for PHP, but the result was the same. I do not know what I can else do, so I'm asking how can I extract those numbers, for further editing, and placing them back...

So, here are my attempts:

The attempt with RegEx:

```
$html = file_get_contents('the link');    
$regex = '#<td id="income"><font color="green"><span data-c="[.*]">(.*?) BTC</span></font></td>#';
if (preg_match($regex, $html)){echo yay;};
```

The attempt with DOM:

```
$html = file_get_contents('the link');    
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load($html);
$element = $dom->getElemetById("income")->innerHTML;
```

Comment: Using a DOM parser is the right approach. Can you show what you tried and what didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not worth going into why your regex doesn't work, IMO (for general regex knowledge though .... a `.` doesn't count for new lines (unless `s` modifier is used) and `.*` in a character class is allowing either of those 2 literal characters).

For the domdocument you need to get further into the DOM tree to get the value. You can use the xpath for this.

```
$html = '<tr>
    <td>Income</td>
    <td id="income">
        <font color="green">
            <span data-c="2250000">0.0225 RP</span>
        </font>
    </td>
</tr>';
$dom = new domdocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
echo $xpath->query('//tr/td[@id="income"]/font/span')[0]->nodeValue;
```

Comment: It complains on `$dom->loadHTML($html)` is it somehow related to the fact that I get the HTML using `file_get_contents()` ? And related to the path, how should I modify  it, if `<tr>` isn't parent in my case?

Comment: Shouldn't be `loadhtml` is looking for a string of HTML. If you `var_dump` that what is it? What is it saying the problem is? Modify the xpath as needed. `$xpath->query('//td[@id="income"]/font/span')[0]->nodeValue;` should get you there.

Comment: I tried to insert directly the link instead of `$html` and it works fine, but I've got another problem, it is related to the last row, I think that the path from `quer()`. In your case it works fine, but how should I modify it in my case, or are there some rules of creating this path? Sorry for (maybe) dumb questions, I'm just new to PHP and do not know how to wield it properly, yet))

Comment: Sorry for misleading both inserting the link and inserting the variable with `file_get_content()` do not work. in the first ase it throws he next error `Recoverable fatal error: Object of class DOMDocument could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 4`, and in the second one this error : `Tag nav invalid in Entity;  htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity; Tag footer invalid in Entity;  Object of class DOMDocument could not be converted to string`

Comment: I cannot post the HTML, but I'll post the code which I'm using

Comment: `function getContent(){
  $html = file_get_contents("/*link*/");
  $baseLink = "/*baseLink*/";
  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  $dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents("/*link*/"));
  $xpath=new DOMXPath($dom);
  echo $xpath->query('//tr/td[@id="income"]/font/span')[0]->nodeValue;
  return str_replace("<head>", "<head><base href="{$baseLink}"/>",$html);
};
echo getContent();` this is the code...

Comment: What are you doing with the `return`? Do you just want the value, or the full dom with the `head` altered? You're going to output that value before the dom with this approach

Comment: well, with `return` I return the whole `$html` with the altered `head`, this way, the code displays the HTML page...

Comment: Isn't the goal to get `0.0225 RP`? You are outputting that before the DOM is built so it won't be accessible, you also aren't returning it so PHP can't use it

Comment: So, in that case I should get the `0.0225 RP` first, then output the DOM? Or shall I try to adding JS too, for an easier way of resolving the problem?

Comment: Well what are you trying to do with that value? If you want to use it in PHP then return it so the PHP has it. If you want it in the DOM put it the proper scope of the DOM. It's hard to follow where this question is heading. Getting the value was answered, it seems we are approaching a different question.

Comment: I have a JSON file, which contains an array of objects, each object containing a field, and these fields are summed together, and I need this value for additioning to the value of those fields in JSON, and the value which I obtain after, should be returned in the HTML.